# Multiple cases use

Tags: sql

I wrote this below in my SELECT. However, it is prompted that

> EthnicGroupCd' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
, (CASE WHEN b.ethnicgroupCd = 'N/A' THEN
         (CASE WHEN g.GenderDsc = 'Male' THEN 'Male' 
         WHEN g.GenderDsc = 'Female' THEN 'Female' END)
      ELSE b.ethnicgroupcd END) as EthnicGenderCd
```

Why it is asking me to group by even though I do not need to display the EthnicGroupCd?

Comment: You do need to display `EthnicGroupCd`, it is in your `ELSE` clause? If `EthnicGroupCd` is "Some Value" then this will be one of your groups, and you need to group by it. By the way, you can simplify your statement to `CASE WHEN b.ethnicgroupCd = 'N/A' THEN g.GenderDsc ELSE b.ethnicgroupcd END` - or even  - `ISNULL(NULLIF(b.ethnicgroupCd,  'N/A'), g.GenderDsc)`

Comment: @GarethD: I meant the EthnicGroupCd is used in the CASE only and it will not be displayed in my SELECT. Isn't the GROUP BY is needed only on other fields in my SELECT to perform the aggregation?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not need to display the EthnicGroupCd?

This doesn't match with:

```
ELSE b.ethnicgroupcd END
```

You can workaround this like:

```
select .... ,(CASE WHEN b.ethnicgroupCd = 'N/A' THEN
                   (CASE WHEN g.GenderDsc = 'Male' THEN 'Male' 
                   WHEN g.GenderDsc = 'Female' THEN 'Female' END)
                   ELSE b.ethnicgroupcd END) as EthnicGenderCd
....
group by ...., (CASE WHEN b.ethnicgroupCd = 'N/A' THEN
                   (CASE WHEN g.GenderDsc = 'Male' THEN 'Male' 
                   WHEN g.GenderDsc = 'Female' THEN 'Female' END)
                   ELSE b.ethnicgroupcd END)
```